# Could not handle scenario where Google Play Services needs updating by GoogleApiAvailability

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, google-play-services

I am currently trying to use the SMS Consent API, and I have laid out logic to check if Google Play Services is updated before I call `startSmsUserConsent()`

```
private val googlePlayServicesIsUpdated: Boolean
        get() {
            val googleApiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance()
            val status = googleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this)

            if (status == ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED) {
                return false
            }

            return true
        }
```

**googlePlayServicesIsUpdated**

```
private fun startSmsUserConsent() {
        SmsRetriever.getClient(this).also {retrieverClient ->
            retrieverClient
                    .startSmsUserConsent(null)
                    .addOnSuccessListener { Log.d(TAG, "listening success") }
                    .addOnFailureListener { Log.d(TAG, "listening failure") }
        }
    }
```

**startSmsUserContent()**

```
if (googlePlayServicesIsUpdated) startSmsUserConsent()
```

**how it's used in onCreate()**

However, unlike what I expected (knowing that the Play Services is not updated), the ConnectionResult always returns as SUCCESS (0), and upon calling startSmsUserConsent(), it shows the "Update Google Play Services" dialog.

This is not friendly for the user because it suggests in its message that the app can't be used if it's not updated, let alone the Play Services API at this moment is only being used to populate the OTP fields automatically.

In essence, I just want to make the code check if Play Services is updated or not before calling `startSmsUserConsent()`, and `isGooglePlayServicesAvailable` so far didn't help fulfill the purpose.

FYI, I am using an emulator with Android 9.0 image with Google APIs (not Google Play)

Comment: `isGooglePlayServicesAvailable` doesn't care about whether the installed Google Play Services version is the latest available version. It only cares about whether the installed version is greater than or equal to the one required by your app.

Comment: And if you're not interested in triggering an update (which could lead to a dialog being shown), then you probably shouldn't be calling `makeGooglePlayServicesAvailable`.

Comment: The "makeGooglePlayServicesAvailable" part is my mistake, and I have removed it from question.